# Android emulator showing offline

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

From within a Java application, I am using emulator '-avd "+emulatorName+" -scale 96dpi -dpi-device 160' command to open an emulator. Emulator is opening however it is always in offline state in DDMS and because of this I am not able to run apk on this. Any Idea on this?

Comment: do you try restart your adb?

Comment: I am not using avd manager, How to restart it using command line?

Answer (score 0):

The "wipe user data" option finally solved my problem. just wipe user data every time you start the emulator(i dont know how to do that from command line). This always works for me! I use windows 8 x64 , eclipse.